# How to create a responsive layout on Tableau dashboards?

Tags: tableau-api

I created 4 tableau worksheets, lets name them `W1, W2, W3, W4` . Each worksheet has a table kind of presentation of data.
I want to present them in a dashboard. So I put 4 vertical layouts and put those sheets in them.
The size of W1 varies according to data. So if data is large there might be a case that a new row will be inserted in the `W1`. You can see the dashboard with layout1(i.e. W1) selected here - [Dashboard1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myrHz.png)

So If height of layout1 increases (i.e. New rows are added in `W1`), I dont want a scroll bar to pop up. I want the other layouts which are below layout1 to adjust according to the size of layout1.
How I can achieve that ?

**EDIT 1** - Here is the image of layout hierarchy for reference [layout hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCkGE.png)

Comment: You probably don't want 4 different vertical layout containers, but perhaps one. Your linked image does not show the layout container arrangement, so its hard to give more specific advice.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I edited the original post with hierarchy structure image. Hope that helps.

Comment: That helps show what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical and Horizontal Layout containers are designed/intended to allow you to explicitly specify how Tableau should position dashboard components (worksheets, titles, text components, image components etc).

Tiled layout containers are introduced automatically by Tableau when you just drop a component on the dashboard. In that case you are handing over some positioning control to Tableau.

Tiled containers work well in the easy cases to get started, but you typically want to delete the tiled layout containers (and any other extra unnecessary levels of containers) when you want to specify positioning yourself. Just right click on a container in the layout hierarchy on the left sidebar to be able to remove them.

You can position components in a vertical container to create a column with multiple components stacked in rows, all having the same widths but with individual row heights controlled by the vertical layout container. Use vertical containers for instance to make sidebars in the margin or a vertical stack of components. Horizontal containers work analogously.

You can either fix the height of each component in a vertical container to constrain the container's choices, or you can leave the height choice to the container - which will consider to the volume of data, height of other containers, and the "fit" settings for each component. Horizontal containers work analogously.

You can nest vertical and horizontal containers to create an arbitrary nesting of rows and columns of components.

If the dashboard size is set to automatic or range, then you can then build responsive dashboards that behave well as the dashboard adjusts size, adjusting the fit, size and nesting and layout hierarchy to get the behavior you want.

So in summary, remove the tiled containers, simplify the container hierarchy to be what you want (maybe just one vertical container in your case), adjust the fixed sizes, fit, dashboard size choices, test, and you should get your dashboard working well.

Sometimes its helpful to have a dummy component (blank, text or image) that you can use to temporarily use while you quickly get your containers setup the way you want - then replace the dummy components with your real worksheets.

Answer (score 1):

When you open the dashboard, you’ll notice a **device preview** button in the dashboard pane.

Clicking the **"device preview"** button reveals two authoring tools that preview the dashboard layout across a variety of device types and screen sizes.

if the dashboard extends beyond the borders of the preview screen. Click the “add tablet layout” button in the preview toolbar. This action would create a customisation of the dashboard that one call's as the **'device layout'**.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Have a look at the EDIT 1 on original post. `Rejection Reason` sub category under **Tiled** hierarchy  is of variable height. I want to adjust other sub categories(i.e. `Segment Reject`, `Counter Offer Reject`, `Manual Reject`) according to the height of `Rejection Reason`. If the whole dashboard has a scroll bar then its fine, but if a particular segment has a scroll bar then it means I have to scroll in that segment to see the data and I don't want that. Hope that helps you understand me more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Coming late to the party on this one but since Tableau 10 it's straightforward to create device specific layouts of the same dashboard. Full details here: https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-responsive-dashboards-for-mobile-and-desktop/